# Find Explicit Linear transformation from given two linear transformations in V3

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

### Question

Find a linear transformation for $T: V_3 \to V_3$ such that
$T(0, 1, 2) = (3, 1, 2)$ and
$T(1, 1, 1) = (2, 2, 2)$.

#### Doubt

I don't know how to solve this, but I have this $T$ which satisfies the condition:
$$
T(x,y,z) = (y+z,3y−z,2y), 
$$
where $z=−x+2y$.

Comment: A linear transformation is completely determined by its values in any basis. Since you have two linearly independent vectors, it is possible to find such a transformation (in fact infinetely many, $V_3$ being $3$-dimensional). Your example seems fine without the condition $z=-x+2y$, why did you add it? $x,y,z$ should be independent of each other

Comment: Can you please tell the procedure to find , I can find the answer when 3 Linearly independent vectors are given, but I don't know how to solve this type of Question.

Comment: You only need one linear transformation, so just choose a third vector independent from the other two. Then, construct $T$ the way you already know how.

Comment: I did that, and found a LI vector also, but since we don't know the linear transformation of the third vector(like we know of the given two vectors) , so I can't put T(γ)  after expanding :- T(aα+bβ+cγ).

Comment: I am guessing you used the cross product $(-1,2,-1)$ for $\gamma$. You can send that wherever you like in $V_3$. We can decide that $T(\gamma) = (1,7,4)$ if we like. That gives the $T$ that you have provided. You could have sent it somewhere else, but you already have a solution that works, so no need to do any more work. The condition $z=-x+2y$ made you restrict to the plane of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but if you just drop that condition you get something with the full $V_3$ domain.

Comment: Thanks, It helped!

Answer (score 1):

First it shoud be "$\mathbf{R}^{3}$" instead of $V_3$ (which is undefined somewhere). Now the solution more or less general in words is: "find a basis for the starting vector space and then find out how $T$ acts on those vectors".  So, consider the construction of a linear transformation $T: \mathbf{R}^3\to\mathbf{R}^3$ with the conditions of the problem.

- Step 1: A basis for $\mathbf{R}^3$.

Setting $v_1=(0,1,2)$ and $v_2=(1,1,1)$ and notice/or to show that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent. The problem is that they are not enough to have a base for $\mathbf{R}^3$, so since no more information is provided we can add a canonical vector and send it to the kernel for example, that is, for $v_3=(0,0,1)$ with $T(v_3)=0$. Note that if the linear transformation there exists, "this new information added" does not affect the first two conditions requested by the problem, that is, "this will have the two conditions requested and one more additionally for convenience" (I try to simplify the philosophy of the idea, I hope it is useful). Synthesizing all that has been said, we have

1. $B=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ a basis (you need to check it) for $\mathbf{R}^3$.
2. $T(v_1)=w_1, T(v_2)=w_2$ and $T(v_3)=0$ with $w_1=(3,1,2)$ and $w_2=(2,2,2)$.

- Step 2: Construction of the rule for $T$.

For this step, take an arbitrary vector from the starting vector space, say, $v=(a,b,c)\in\mathbf{R}^3$. Since $B$ is a basis for $\mathbf{R}^3$ there exists $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$ such that $v=\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\alpha_3v_3$ (this will create you a system of linear equations and you will need to find each $\alpha_k$ as $\alpha_k(a,b,c)$). Then we get
$$\alpha_1=b-a,\quad \alpha_2=a,\quad \alpha_3=a-2b+c$$
Then, through the definition of linear transformation we build the rule for $T$, that is,
$$T(a,b,c)=\alpha_1T(v_1)+\alpha_2T(v_2)+\alpha_3T(v_3)$$
Substitution give
$$T(a,b,c)=(b-a)(3,1,2)+a(2,2,2)+(a-2b+c)(0,0,0)$$
Hence an answer is
$$\boxed{T(a,b,c)=(b-a)(3,1,2)+a(2,2,2)}$$
(or you can "write it more condensed by doing the operations scaling by vector and adding vectors" if you want).

Note that this rule satisfies the requested properties:

1. $T(0,1,2)=(2-1)(3,2,1)+0(2,2,2)=(3,1,2)$ as desired.
2. $T(1,1,1)=(1-1)(3,2,1)+1(2,2,2)=(2,2,2)$ as desired.

and that is a rule that satisfies the conditions of the problem. But of course due to the "degree of freedom" it also satisfies that

3. $T(0,0,1)=(0-0)(3,1,2)+0(2,2,2)=(0,0,0)$ as desired.

NB:

a) The given schematic is "quite general" so you can apply these two steps to similar problems (a good practice).

b) Of course, there are problems where the schematic might seem incomplete (sometimes it may be necessary to remove redundant information or invoke dimensional theorems first).

c) I hope this is useful and that it falls within the framework of questions that can be answered under the MSE guidelines.